# Was the angelology in [Tobit 12:15] based only on [1 Enoch 20:1-8]?

Tags: angels, intertextuality, 1-enoch, tobit

**We read in [Tobit 12:15] a reference to [1 Enoch 20:3].**

> "I am Raphael, one of the seven holy angels, which present the prayers of the saints, and which go in and out before the glory of the Holy One."

**Which verse in the Tanakh was [Tobit 12:15] based on? - None.**

- [1 Enoch 20:1] states: "These are the names of the Holy angels who watch."
- [1 Enoch 20:2-8] lists all 7 Archangels.

**In [1 Enoch 20:3] we discover "Raphael" for the first time outside of the Tanakh** :

> "Raphael, one of the Holy angels, who is in charge of the spirits of men".

---

**Was the angelology in [Tobit 12:15] based only on [1 Enoch 20:1-8] ?**

Comment: They are more probably both based on a third common source or series of common myths.

Comment: From Wickipedia: Tobit is considered a work of fiction with only some historical references, combining prayers, ethical exhortation, humour and adventure with elements drawn from folklore, wisdom tale, travel story, romance and comedy. It offered the diaspora (the Jews in exile) guidance on how to retain Jewish identity, and its message was that God tests his people's faith, hears their prayers, and redeems the covenant community (i.e., the Jews)

Comment: The seven-branched [menorah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_menorah) signified the [seven classical planets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_planet), known to the ancient Babylonians, whose influence on Judaism is well documented. Notice also that, depending on context, the same biblical expression, *hosts of heaven*, denotes both stars and angels. There is also a matter of chronology: in order for [Tobit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Tobit) to be inspired by [Enoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_Enoch), the latter has to precede the former; not sure if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Enoch is the only known source that calls the seven angels by name. Nor does the name Raphael appear anywhere else prior to Tobit. However, angels seem to have been much discussed in the period after the Babylonian exile beginning with the Book of Daniel, which names Michael and Gabriel. The [Book of Jubilees](https://weekly.israelbiblecenter.com/angels-creation-jubilees) refers to seven (or more) orders of angels:

- the angels of the presence,
- the angels of sanctification,
- the angels of the spirit of fire,
- the angels of the spirit of the winds,
- the angels of the spirit of the clouds and darkness and snow and hail and frost,
  and the angels of resoundings and thunder and lightning,
- the angels of the spirits of cold and heat and winter and springtime and harvest and summer, and all of the spirits of his creatures which are in heaven and on earth.

So in terms of the angel named Raphael, Enoch is probably Tobit's source. However it would not be accurate to say Tobit's angelology is based only on Enoch.